# Positioning points along a line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build the following component with CSS, but I can't get the first and last point to sit flush against the ends of the line.

[image]

It must be able to support an arbitrary number of points (between 1 and 4) and I can't rely on flexbox being there either.

I have a React component that's generating HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col first" style="width:33%">
    <div class="marker complete"></div>
    <label>Feedback</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="width:33%">
    <div class="marker partial"></div>
    <label>Observation</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col last" style="width:33%">
    <div class="marker review"></div>
    <label>Documentation</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript calculates the column sizes before rendering and [in my codepen implementation](http://codepen.io/danthedev/pen/PzrWOk?editors=1100), I'm just centering all the content in each column.

I can sort of hack a solution by using the `first` and `last` classes to relatively position the end items, but invariably when the screen size changes, I start to get the edges of the line poking out from behind the points.

Does anyone know of a more sensible layout to start building this with?

Comment: Assuming you can't rely flexbox, does that mean you can't use `calc` either? And what about pseudo elements? Maybe easier: which browsers do you need support for?

Comment: IE9 is the lowest I need to cover. Although I can't actually use pseudo elements either, but that's a [different limitation](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Aphrodite, but are you sure psuedo elements are not possible? Hover styles seem to be, and they are normally not inline either.

Comment: There's no mention of them in the docs, but I just had a look through the source and they show up in the tests. So I guess they work.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to set `row` as `display: table-row`, and then use a pseudo element to generate the horizontal bar. However, you run into the issue that you cannot know with CSS and HTML alone what the position of the first and last circle is relative to the size of the container. Therefore, it is not possible to use a full width item.

Another approach is using the labels as root items for the pseudo elements. They are always the full width of the column, so they give a nice indication what needs to be used.

The [following proposed solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzrWgb) should work with IE9. The only *special* thing that is used is `calc` and `after`. (Instead of `calc` you can also use a `transform: translate` if you want.)

The basic idea is to use a table row, which would automatically scale nicely, and then use the labels as roots on which you can build the progress bar.

```
label:after {
  content: "";
  height: .5em;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc((100% - 1.5em) / 2); /* -1 to compensate text, -.5 for height bar */
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.first label:after, .last label:after {
  width: 50%;
}

.first label:after {
  left: auto; 
  right: 0;
}

.single label:after {content: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go. I assume this is what you are looking for.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="width:33%">
    <div class="marker marker1 complete"></div>
    <label>Feedback</label>
  </div>
<div class="col2" style="width:33%">
    <div class="marker marker2 partial"></div>
    <label>Observation</label>
</div>
<div class="col3" style="width:33%">
   <div class="marker marker3 review"></div>
     <label>Documentation</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/e6nm2rbv/

*if JS was/is allowed I can put some conditions in it based on number and word length and adjust marker indentions.

Basically I used display blocks, margins and secondary marker classes for each block.

Comment: Thanks, but that still has most of the problems. The line still extends beyond the outermost points and if I used the control with 1, 2 or 4 items it would break.

Comment: I didn't see a reference to the line not sticking out. Did you mean more like this ... check updated JSfiddle

Comment: If text-align can be set to left and right for the first and last items respectively, the issue is easy to solve indeed.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
.marker {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.complete {
  background-color: blue;
}
.partial {
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 8px solid lightgray;
}
.review {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.col:not(:last-child) > .marker:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 67%;
  height: 0;
  border: 3px solid lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16.5%;
  top: 12.5px;
  z-index: -10;
}
/* ------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 100px;
}
.point {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 30px;
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  height: 0;
  border: 3px solid lightgray;
  flex: 1 0;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.border {
  background-color: lightgray;
  background-image: radial-gradient(at center center, blue 0, blue 8px, transparent 8px, transparent 100%);
}
.point label {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Non flex</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col first">
    <div class="marker complete"></div>
    <label>Feedback</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="marker partial"></div>
    <label>Observation</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col last">
    <div class="marker review"></div>
    <label>Documentation</label>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Flex</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="point blue">
    <label>Feedback</label>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="point blue border">
    <label>Observation</label>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="point lightblue">
    <label>Documentation</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He explicitly said he could not rely on flex.

Comment: [sarcasm on] calc is definitely the best solution [sarcasm off]

Comment: Considering the restrictions, yes. (Though you can easily solve that with transform if you want to.) Don't act so immaturely when someone points you the obvious that you missed, which makes your solution invalid.